# Convert unnamed regularly strucrured R list into named R list

Tags: r

I have a strange R list, in which odd list elements that are strings should be names of even list elements. Some elements are lists inside the lists. The depth of the list is not predefined in advance. And the simplified structure of the list is approximately:

```
a <- list("key0",
          "value0",
          "key",
          list("key1", "value1",
               "key2", "value2", 
               "key3",  list("key6", "value6"),
               "key4", "value4",
               "key5", list(list(list("key7", "value7")))
          ))
```

How from list `a` can I get a regular named R list `b`?

```
b <- list(key0 = "value0",
          key = list(key1 = "value1",
                     key2 = "value2", 
                     key3 = list(key6  = "value6"),
                     key4 = "value4",
                     key5 = list(list(list(key7 = "value7")))
          ))
```

Does list `a` like data structure have any special technical name?

Comment: Doesn't have a name in R although it is what a JSON structure might look like after being imported into R.

Comment: `b <- a[seq(2,length(a),2)]` followed by `names(b) <- a[seq(1,length(a)-1,2)]` might get you part of the way there, although you would need to abstract it to a function and apply it recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a recursive function :

```
fun <- function(x){
  x <- lapply(x,function(y) if (is.list(y)) y <- fun(y) else y)
  if(!is.null(names(x)) | length(x) == 1) return(x)
  x <- setNames(x[seq_along(x)%%2 == 0], x[seq_along(x)%%2 == 1])
  x
}
res <- fun(a)

identical(b,res)
# [1] TRUE
```